# 301 Moved Permanently on nginx server

Tags: http, url-redirection

If I request this:

```
http://mysite.com/\/\http://evilzone.org
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://mysite.com/\/\http://evilzone.org
```

Is it a vulnerability?

Answer (score 2):

No. It means you have a global redirect from http to https before you check if it's a valid URL.

That would not be considered a vulnerability normally.